# Should the name of the sport be included in the question title?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Start with examples:

- [How to attack zone defence?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-to-attack-zone-defense) (tagged Basketball)
- [Is it possible to effectively practice zone defence in **basketball** if you don't have 10 people?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/18/is-it-possible-to-effectively-practice-zone-defence-in-basketball-if-you-dont-h) (also tagged)

Now the question is, should we encourage adding the name of the sport in the question title or is the tag sufficient enough?

*My own view* is that having the sport in the title helps because that is the first thing you read. It saves you looking through tags if it is unclear to you what the question is about.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend against it. If the most-used tag is high enough, it will automatically be appended to the title of the page. And the most used tags will be put first.

The only reason it would need to be there is to catch people's attention, which is what the tags are for in the first place.

This isn't to say that if I saw it I would edit it out, because that's a particularly minor edit. Even if I was editing the post for some other reason, I still wouldn't remove it. But I wouldn't encourage users to do it.